GitLab merge remote master to remote feature branch without git clone
I have a repository with master branch (protected) and abcd branch (random unprotected branch). Is there a way to merge master to abcd without git clone at all (empty local)? so, everything happens on the server. so, maybe like a runnable script on GitLab server? Or anything of the sort?

You can merge branches with the gitlab UI.  Otherwise, in order to affect the repository, you need to have the repository.

@TimRoberts but this gitlab UI thing, it's manual by human hands, correct? or is it doable with script and some token via API? or anything else that can be done programmatically?
